# Sigabrt error xcode, and viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, sigabrt

Im not going to post my code because i dont think that its an error with that but im going to ask some question about viewcontrollers because i think my lack of understanding of them is what is causing it.

So i have a multipage registration page in my app, the first page asks for email the second page is name and so on. I get this error when trying to present the same view controller across all the pages.

```
Attempt to present <Safisa.RegPageViewController: 0x7f9c085e4130>  on 
<Safisa.RegPageViewController: 0x7f9c0a23a920> which is already 
presenting <UIAlertController: 0x7f9c0842b0b0>
2016-07-06 11:23:14.820 Safisa[6027:265977] *** Terminating app due to 
uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: 
'[<Safisa.RegPageViewController 0x7f9c0a278f00> 
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-
compliant for the key passwordRegButton.'
```

I also get an error that is Thread 1: signal Sigabrt for the pre built class

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Any tips on how i can fix this guys?

Comment: You are trying to present the same instance of you view controller across all pages, you can't do that

Comment: So i need to make a new view controller for each page?